# NPE in Test Case

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I was writing the test case of my controller class, it has the getModel() method that returns the model object. Here is the snippet of method :

```
@Override
 public ContentModel getModel() {
    if(getCurrentPage().getDepth() > 0) {
        parentTitle = getCurrentPage().getParent().getTitle();
        parentPath = getCurrentPage().getParent().getPath();
    }
    else {
        parentTitle = "No Parent";
        parentPath = "No Parent";
    }
    return ComponentModelBuilder.build(
            rcm -> rcm.setHeading(heading),
            rcm -> rcm.setParentTitle(parentTitle),
            rcm -> rcm.setParentPath(parentPath)
    );
}
```

Here is the test case :

```
@Test
    public void getModelShouldReturnValidModelWhenInjected() {

        Page parentPage = mock(Page.class);

        ContentModel contentModel = contentController.getModel();
        assertThat(ContentModel instanceof contentModel, is(true));
        assertThat(((ContentModel) contentModel).getHeading(), is("Heading   For Banner"));

    }
```

Here how can we mock the currentPage object and use it in my test case for parentTitle and parentPath.

```
stacktrace :
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.prj.project.aem.components.base.BaseController.getCurrentPage(BaseController.java:127)
    at com.prj.project.aem.components.content.contentController.getModel(contentController.java:61)
```

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace please?

Comment: I bet `contentController` is either never instantiated or is a mock object.

Comment: I bet that he expects `Page parentPage = mock(Page.class);` mock the object `getCurrentPage().getParent()`

Comment: yes, contentController is a mock object.